# Reinitialize parallax.js on window resize?

Tags: jquery, resize, parallax, parallax.js

I'm using the [parallax.js](http://wagerfield.github.io/parallax/) for a responsive portfolio website. There is a "mansory" grid, which has "parallaxed" images in it. When I load the website in the smartphone view (with a smaller grid width) and increase the window up to desktop view, the plugin does not recalculate the distances, and that the image slides out of the grid. I think it needs a reinitialise when resizing and I tried the "calibrate" option, with no luck:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".exhibition").parallax({
        calibrateX: true,
        calibrateY: true
    });
}).resize();
```

On the demo page it seems to reinit or recalculate the distances. How can I archieve that? Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you can replicate this on jsfiddle?

Comment: Tried to set up a fiddle, but the parallax.js won't work. maybe you know why? http://jsfiddle.net/8WS8h/

Comment: Hmmm, for some reason it fails on `document.body.appendChild`... which makes no sense. Maybe it the way jsfiddle loads external resources.